# VBA hit button on IE page

Tags: excel, vba, explorer

What i am trying to do is to open a site, and then press a button. i can't make it work though, so i am asking for all of you experienced programmers!

The button xml record is:

```
z-menu-item-inner-r"><span class="z-menu-item-space"></span></td></tr></tbody></table></a></td><td id="z_e6_mm" align="left" z.type="Menuit2" class="z-menu-item " style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;" z.zcls="z-menu-item" z.top="true"><a href="/NTS/NTSBatchJobs.zul" class="z-menu-item-cnt"><table id="z_e6_mm!a" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="z-menu-item-body " style="width: auto;"><tbody><tr><td class="z-menu-item-inner-l"><span class="z-menu-item-space"></span></td><td class="z-menu-item-inner-m"><div><button id="z_e6_mm!b" type="button" class="z-menu-item-btn">**HIT ME**&nbsp;</button></div></td><td class="
```

The button i am trying to press is named:
**HIT ME**

The code i am using is:

```
Sub IE_Auto()


    Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "mysite"

    Set elems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each e In elems
            If e.Name = "Hit Me" Then
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
     Next e
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `getElementByID("z_e6_mm!b")` method to return the instance of that button. The element *id* is unique within the document, no need for iteration.

```
Dim btn as Object
Set btn = IE.Document.getElementByID("z_e6_mm!b")
btn.Click
```

NOTE: May not work with certain version(s) of IE.

Also worth noting, you could have a simple issue of case-sensitive comparison returning false, and never clicking the button, because: `"Hit Me" != "HIT ME"`.  You could control for this by forcing a `UCASE` or `LCASE` evaluation of the button's text, but that seems less reliable than using the ID property.

Also note: that's not the element's `.Name` but it's `.InnerText`

As you observe, the ID property is changing so you can't reliably program to it. In that case, you're left with brute force iteration, and comparing some non-unique property like `innerText`:

```
Dim btn as Object
For each btn in IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If btn.innerText = "**HIT ME**&nbsp;" Then '<~~~ MODIFY AS NEEDED  ###
        btn.click
        Exit For 'break out of the loop
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i am getting run-time error back:automation error. The Interface is unknown and it stops in Set btn = IE.Document.getElementById("z_e6_mm!b")

Comment: requires IE8+ what version have you? You may also need a ready/waiting loop for IE to allow the page to finish Loading.  ALso, verify the correct element ID from the XML.

Comment: My IE version is 8.0.7601.17514. I added a waiting loop also, for 10 seconds :Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now). How can i verify that is the correct element? i search with the button title!

Comment: Application.Wait will not work. You need to use While: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 and Not IE.Busy

Comment: It seems that button id is changing every time the link is opened. Is there a way to get current button id?

Comment: @Golemic no, the ID *is* the unique identifier, so the only way to obtain the button's ID would be to do a `For/Next` loop over all of the buttons `getElementByTagName("button")` and compare some other property for equivalence. It seems you will need to do that, and just check each button's `innerText` property. I will update the answer...

Comment: Thanks David!Could you help me more with that? Is there a link with the code i need, so i can check out?

Comment: Worked great! Thank you David Zemens